# FeedbackPanel stylize/change message

Tags: wicket

How to stylize my Feedback message? Now it's like a normal html list element.

How to change my Feedback messages for validators like email validator?

I know that I can change the .setRequired() message with a property file and the following code:

```
  Required=Provide a ${label} or else...

  form.userId.Required=You have to provide a name
```

Comment: Maybe you should check JavaDoc or the wicket wiki before asking several questions at once...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to subclass FeedbackPanel (or reimplement it on your own) and override the `newMessageDisplayComponent(String id, FeedbackMessage message)` method to return any component of your liking. See [JavaDoc of FeedbackPanel](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/panel/FeedbackPanel.html#newMessageDisplayComponent%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.wicket.feedback.FeedbackMessage%29)

As for custom validator messages: When calling `error` in your custom validator you can supply a resourceKey by which the application tries to find your error message. As above: [JavaDoc is your friend](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/validation/validator/AbstractValidator.html#error%28org.apache.wicket.validation.IValidatable,%20java.lang.String%29).